# How to effectively select the predictors for Bayesian linear regression model?

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression, linear-model, multicollinearity, predictor

I have around 20 independent (or not strongly correlated) predictor variables. And there are about 20 observations for each variable and the outcome.

I want to build a Bayesian linear regression model using these data. How to effectively select the predictors, since 20 predictors are too many?

Maybe can use information criteria (AIC, WAIC)? Do I have to try each possible combination of the model predictors?

Comment: I don't have too many observations, that's why I want to cut some predictor variables.

Comment: If you want to go full Bayesian, try spike and slab prior(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike-and-slab_variable_selection). Or there are many papers that suggest variable selection via Zellner's g-prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several types of priors for conducting variable selection have been developed in the context of linear regression models. One the most recent proposals are non-local priors, which are implemented in the R package mombf:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mombf/index.html

In your case, $2^{20}$ models are not that many (1048576), and it may be feasible to explore all of them. If you want to conduct a faster, efficient selection, you may want to have a look at either of these two papers (which are also part of the mombf package):

> [Variable Selection Via Gibbs Sampling](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1993.10476353). Edward I. George; Robert E. McCulloch. Journal of the American Statistical Association

and

> J.G. Scott and J.O Berger. `[Bayes and empirical Bayes multiplicity adjustment in the variable selection problem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1278861454)`. The Annals of Statistics.

Comment: Could you give links for the papers?

Comment: @mdewey Done, but apparently I cannot post more than two links as a new user. Could you please give me hand with that?

Comment: I tried editing it but that does not fix it. At least the information is now there even if not as pretty as it could be.

Answer (score 5):

See Juho Piironen and Aki Vehtari (2017). Comparison of Bayesian predictive methods for model selection. Statistics and Computing, 27(3):711-735.
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-016-9649-y
which shows that most approaches overfit during the selection, and that projection predictive approach performs the best.

The projection predictive model selection has been implemented in projpred R package https://github.com/stan-dev/projpred which supports rstanarm models.
For a quick intro see https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/stan-dev/projpred/blob/master/vignettes/quickstart.html
We have tested projection predictive model selection with many small n large n datasets up to 20k predictors.